# Why am I receiving errors when using views and controllers created via scaffolding with MVC 5 / EF 6 (inheritance) derived classes?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-5

Why am I receiving errors when using views and controllers created via scaffolding with MVC 5 / EF 6 (inheritance) derived classes?

My background: I am a previous Powerbuilder (client/server programmer) that is endeavoring to learn web-based programming.
I chose ASP.NET and purchased an MSDN license to use Visual Studio 2013 and have been learning by books, online training and plain old hacking on the computer.
The best test is to create some sample application and so here I am.  I am learning the MVC and Code First EF because there is so much good info and samples to be had.
However, I am stuck on my inheritance example.

I have 3 classes: AircrewMember derived from Airman derived from Person. They compile without error.
I have a class DbInitializer so "Code First" will create the database.  I actually use SQL scripts to load my test data.
I have a class StanEvalDb for the database context info.
I have included pertinent information from web.config.

The problem:

When I use scaffolding to create a controller and views based off of the Airman class (derived from Person), the result returns with errors.

```
        Airman airman = db.People.Find(id);
```

Error   1
Cannot implicitly convert type 'SEMX1.Entities.Person' to 'SEMX1.Entities.Airman'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    D:\Projects\VC2013\2015\06-Jun\SEMX1\SEMX1.Web\Controllers\AirmenController.cs  31  29  SEMX1.Web

I think I understand the Table per Hierarchy (TPH) and that physically only one table (People) is created to house all "3" tables.
I am at a loss... I have googled and read many articles but I have no idea how to proceed.  Has anyone seen this or tried this?
I assume I am overlooking something simple but I am out of ideas.  Any help would be appreciated!

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SEMX1.Entities
{
    public class Person
    {
        public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name* ")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The First Name field is required.")]
        public virtual string PersonFirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Middle Initial ")]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public virtual string PersonMidInit { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name* ")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Last Name field is required.")]
        public virtual string PersonLastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("SSN* ")]
        [StringLength(11)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The SSN field is required.")]
        public virtual string PersonSSN { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("DOB* ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The DOB field is required.")]
        public virtual DateTime? PersonDOB { get; set; }

        public virtual int CivilRankId { get; set; }

        //public virtual int LifeEventId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<LifeEvent> LifeEvents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SEMX1.Entities
{
    public class Airman : Person
        {
            public virtual int MilitaryRankId { get; set; }
            public virtual int MilitaryUnitId { get; set; }
            public virtual int AfscId { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<CareerEvent> CareerEvents { get; set; }
        }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SEMX1.Entities
{
    public class AircrewMember : Airman
    {
        public virtual int AviationTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual int AirMissionId { get; set; }
        public virtual int AircraftId { get; set; }
        public virtual int CrewPositionId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ExperienceRatingId { get; set; }
        public virtual int AirmanshipId { get; set; }
        public virtual int TacticalDayRatingId { get; set; }
        public virtual int TacticalNightRatingId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AircrewEvent> AircrewEvents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using SEMX1.Entities;
using System.IO;

namespace SEMX1.Web.DataContexts
{
    public class DbInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StanEvalDb>
    {
        protected override void Seed(StanEvalDb context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            // using SQL scripts to load database with test data
            // easier way to get around identity key field problems


        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using SEMX1.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace SEMX1.Web.DataContexts
{
    public class StanEvalDb : DbContext
    {
        public StanEvalDb() : base("StanEvalContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<StanEvalDb>(new DbInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LifeEvent> LifeEvents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CivilRank> CivilRanks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MilitaryRank> MilitaryRanks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MilitaryUnit> MilitaryUnits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MilUnitType> MilUnitTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AFSC> AFSCList { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CareerEvent> CareerEvents { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Airman> Airmen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AviationType> AviationTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AirMission> AirMissions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Aircraft> AircraftList { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CrewPosition> CrewPositions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ExperienceRating> ExperienceRatings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Airmanship> AirmanshipList { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TacticalDayRating> TacticalDayRatings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TacticalNightRating> TacticalNightRatings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AircrewEvent> AircrewEvents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AircrewMember> Aircrew { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            //modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            //    .HasMany(p => p.LifeEvents).WithMany(l => l.People)
            //    .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("PersonID")
            //    .MapRightKey("LifeEventID")
            //    .ToTable("LifeEventPersons"));

            //modelBuilder.Entity<Airman>()
            //    .HasMany(a => a.CareerEvents).WithMany(c => c.Airmen)
            //    .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("PersonID")
            //    .MapRightKey("CareerEventID")
            //    .ToTable("CareerEventAirmen"));

            //modelBuilder.Entity<AircrewMember>()
            //    .HasMany(a => a.AircrewEvents).WithMany(c => c.Aircrew)
            //    .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("PersonID")
            //    .MapRightKey("AircrewEventID")
            //    .ToTable("AircrewEventAircrew"));

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Web.config (Pertinent Information)

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StanEvalContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=REDCARBOSS2-LAP\RCB2SRV2012;Initial Catalog=DB_25213_SEMX1;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SEMX1.Entities;
using SEMX1.Web.DataContexts;

namespace SEMX1.Web.Controllers
{
    public class AirmenController : Controller
    {
        private StanEvalDb db = new StanEvalDb();

        // GET: Airmen
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.People.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Airmen/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Airman airman = db.People.Find(id);
            if (airman == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(airman);
        }

        // GET: Airmen/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Airmen/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersonId,PersonFirstName,PersonMidInit,PersonLastName,PersonSSN,PersonDOB,CivilRankId,MilitaryRankId,MilitaryUnitId,AfscId")] Airman airman)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.People.Add(airman);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(airman);
        }

        // GET: Airmen/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Airman airman = db.People.Find(id);
            if (airman == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(airman);
        }

        // POST: Airmen/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PersonId,PersonFirstName,PersonMidInit,PersonLastName,PersonSSN,PersonDOB,CivilRankId,MilitaryRankId,MilitaryUnitId,AfscId")] Airman airman)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(airman).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(airman);
        }

        // GET: Airmen/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Airman airman = db.People.Find(id);
            if (airman == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(airman);
        }

        // POST: Airmen/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Airman airman = db.People.Find(id);
            db.People.Remove(airman);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You may have more success getting help if you can reduce your question down to the bare essentials.  Can you reproduce your problem in a smaller, easier to read example?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Airman airman = db.Airmen.Find(id); ? Doesn't look like your doing anything People specific. Could also try Airman airman = (Airman)db.People.Find(id);

Comment: Airman airman = db.Airmen.Find(id);

I swear I did this earlier but now it works... to clear the compile error...but...

Comment: So I run the application and run the Create window for Person entity and no problem... I could create and save a new record to the database.
However when I run the Create window for Airman entity I get:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SEMX1.Entities.Person]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SEMX1.Entities.Airman]'.

Comment: This is at the top of the Create view for Airman.  Should it be something else?  I saw an article about IEnumerable but could not make it work.

@model SEMX1.Entities.Airman

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it cannot implicitly cast and is asking you to explicitly cast. Try replacing this:

```
Airman airman = db.People.Find(id);
```

With:

```
Airman airman = (Airman)db.People.Find(id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However the Create method is where the problem is.  Based off your idea I attempted the following change:
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersonId,PersonFirstName,PersonMidInit,PersonLastName,PersonSSN,PersonDOB,CivilRankId,MilitaryRankId,MilitaryUnitId,AfscId")] Airman airman)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //db.People.Add(airman);
                db.Airmen.Add(airman);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View(airman);

but received the same error...

Comment: OLD                //db.People.Add(airman);
NEW                db.Airmen.Add(airman);

Comment: I would be more than happy to define this as a System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable... can anyone steer me as to how to accomplish this?